# Database and hermetization in Java

Tags: java, sql, dao

I am learning Java and I want to save application state. In object-oriented programming, we should hide implementation and share functionality by interfaces. It works fine until I don't need to restore data from a database.

For example. If the application contains IdGenerator class build with a used singleton design pattern I can use it to generate unique ids during object creation. So interface share only getId() method. But what if I want to restore objects from a database? I need to setId() method only to restore objects. Is there some solution to that (I mean some design pattern which solves the problem)? 
I have the same problem with Spring and JUnit. I don't know if I don't understand something or it forces to use getters and setters for everything that we want to inject.

I created example project:

In package model.people is interface Person:

```
public interface Person {
    long getId();
    Person setName(String name);
    String getName();
}
```

So the same package has implementation class:

```
public class PersonImpl implements Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    public PersonImpl(String name){
        this.id = IdGenerator.getInstance().getID();
    }

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public Person setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

IdGenerator class is like that:

```
public class IdGenerator {
    private static IdGenerator instance;
    private long lastId;

    private IdGenerator(){
        lastId = 0;
    }

    public static IdGenerator getInstance(){
        if (instance==null){
            instance = new IdGenerator();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public long getID(){
        return lastId++;
    }

}
```

So the id is unique for every object and it can't be changed. It's a reason that Person interface don't provide a method named setId(); In the result I can create any class for restore data from database or file:

```
public class DataLoader {
    public boolean loadData(String filePath){
        .
        .
        .
        .

        long loadedId = ....
        String loadedName = ....


        Person personRestoredObject = PersonImpl(loadedName);

    }

}
```

but it can't restore old id. Id is create by constructor. So is there any design pattern for the problem?

I see a solution for that, by adding a Factory class which will have an access to setId() method on package level or special constructor available only on package level. But I don't see any possibility to not provide a method to setId() in practice because then I can't restore an object's of data source. Am I wrong?

Comment: It would help us understand the problem better, if you could provide some code examples.

Comment: Ok. I will add it.

Comment: You might be looking for a [object database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_database)( ORDBMS ) instead which  stores as objects instead of “relational tables”